# How can I plot this simple graph (Refer Image) in R?

Tags: r

I'm very new to R Programming. So please excuse for such a simple doubt.
[image: How to plots this graph in R?]

I want to plot the above graph. The x & y values are sequence from 0 to 2560. I want plot a a curve on the points where x*y=10^6.

What are the line required in R Programming Language.

Comment: the legend in your graph does not correspond to the graph of function $y=10^6/x$, is this intentional?

Comment: Thanks @mpiktas. My mistake. 
And my intention is not y=10^6/x. I want to make a graph with x & y values and the mark the points(curve) where the values of x & y satisfies (x*y=10^6). Is it possible? Not sure if this is mathematical correct or not.

Comment: For reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vector_Video_Standards2.svg I want to plot the line which acts as the boundary for yellow on the lower right (>1M pixels)

Answer (score 7):

I think all you need is:

```
 curve(1e6/x,0,2560)
```

EDIT in light of comments:
Or perhaps:

```
plot(...<your data>...)
curve(1e6/x, 1e6/2560,2560, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: This solution is a lot nicer than my "hackish" try!

Comment: +1, did not know about curve :) Always used plot directly.

Comment: For completeness, perhaps add `text(2000, 30000, expression(paste("where xy=", 10^6)))`?

Comment: @mpiktas: Good point ;)

Comment: But I want to make graph with x & y values and the mark the points(curve) where the values of x & y satisfies (x*y=10^6)

Comment: @Saneef, my comment above is irrelevant now, since you fixed the graph. I will delete it. Now with @csgillespie comment it will be replicated.

Comment: @Saneef: to add this curve to an existing plot, use the option `add=TRUE`. See ?curve.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to compute all *y* values at every given *x* values, like:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:2560)
df$y <- 10^6/df$x
# the latter equivalent to:
# df <- within(df,y<-10^6/x)
```

And after plot the dataframe:

```
plot(df, type="l", main=expression(f(x) == frac(10^{6},x)))
```

[image]

Comment: why use loop? df <- within(df,y<-10^6/x) is much nicer and more efficient. Also OP asks for line, so you need to supply type="l" in your plot function.

Comment: @mpiktas: true! It is terrible, that I fall into a habbit always using loops :( I edit my answer based on your suggestions.